# Howto inherit from a base class within a list of child class objects

Tags: python, class

Random example from www:

```
class Deck(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.cards = []
        self.name = name
        for suit in range(4):
            for rank in range(1, 14):
                self.cards.append(Card(suit, rank))

    def print_deck(self):
        for card in self.cards:
            print(card)

class Card(Deck):
    suits = ["Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"]
    ranks = ["narf", "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7",
             "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"]

    def __init__(self, suit=0, rank=0):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.ranks[self.rank] + " of " + self.suits[self.suit])



d = Deck("magic_cards")
d.print_deck()
```

I want to use the variable `name` from Deck in my Card class.
I've tried `super(Deck, self).init(name)` in the child class.
Then i receive errors like:

```
TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

How to do this step correctly?

Edit:
I could just pass class attributes to certain methods in my child class.
This would be good enough.

```
class Deck():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.cards = []
        self.name = name
        for suit in range(4):
            for rank in range(1, 14):
                self.cards.append(Card(suit, rank))

    def print_deck(self):
        for card in self.cards:
            print(card)

class Card():
    suits = ["Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"]
    ranks = ["narf", "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7",
             "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"]

    def __init__(self, suit=0, rank=0):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.ranks[self.rank] + " of " + self.suits[self.suit])

    def printchild(self, name):
        return name



d = Deck("magic_cards")
c = d.cards[0]
print(c.printchild(d.name))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you have a general design problem. Inheritance is a *is a* relation. A Card should not be a Deck but have a reference to its Deck, so I would prefer containment to inheritance here:

```
class Deck(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.cards = []
        self.name = name
        for suit in range(4):
            for rank in range(1, 14):
                self.cards.append(Card(suit, rank, self))   # pass a Deck ref. to Card

    ...

class Card():
    ...
    def __init__(self, suit=0, rank=0, deck=None):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank
        self.deck = deck
    ...
```

Comment: Yes, that could work. I guess my real world problem would be better described by Excel. I have a table object and this have many row object. The row object would have some methods that use attributes from my table object.

Comment: @incognito: then you should use the *containment* pattern (*has a* relation) instead of inheritance (*is a* relation).

Answer (score 1):

**Classes can be seen as object constructors or object templates.**

For example, you have a card - *but what type of card do you have? what is its suit? what is it's number.*

The way you have formatted the code is kind of wierd. You can't really pass a class to another class object. Taking the explanation I gave earlier, why would you pass a template to a template??

**You might want to try something like this:**

```py
class card():
    
    def __init__(suit,rank):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank


ace_of_spades = card("spade","ace")

deck = []
deck.append[ace_of_spades]
```

Comment: Hmm, maybe it is a bad example. My real world problem is more complex. I have a base class and this should contain a list of subclasses. I would like to decide for dirfferent options within my card object depending on the name of my deck.

Comment: @incognito the example is pretty confusing - there isn't really a reason to inherit Deck in Card.  What exactly are you trying to achieve?  Why would you want a base class with a list of subclasses?

Comment: You may want to try doing some simple class example first before moving to some more complex problems @incognito

Comment: @incognito maybe check out this website. It covers almost exactly what you want to do: https://realpython.com/python-data-classes/

Comment: @Gunt.r Thank you, will read it. Inspired by your answer i've seen another way. I've edited my initial post.